# Compare price changes

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, compare

I am trying to create a view to report what stores have had a price change in the last 24 hours. In this report, I need to calculate and display the amount of of store, state, city, address and amount of change.

This is what I have tried so far but it is not comparing the store and it's price correctly. It compares another store's price in the output. This is for an sqlite database but will eventually move to MySql.

```
select
   p_today.`url`,
   p_today.`company`,   
   p_today.`state`,   
   p_today.`city`,   
   p_today.`location`,   
   p_today.`address`,
   p_today.`timerecorded`,
   p_yest.price as `yesterday`,
   p_today.price as `today`,   
   p_yest.address,   
   p_yest.`timerecorded`,
   (p_today.price - p_yest.price) as `change`
from
   prices p_today
   inner join prices p_yest on
       p_today.address = p_yest.address
       and date(p_today.`timerecorded`) > date(p_yest.`timerecorded`) + datetime('now')
       and p_yest.price > 0
where p_today.price > 0
    and date(p_today.`timerecorded`) = CURRENT_DATE    
    and change > 0.1    
group by p_today.`address`
order by `change` desc
```

Comment: What do you mean another store? do you have multiple database, one for each store? If that is the case you should specify the database(store) name in your from  table clause.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I am storing prices for all stores in one table. The are many stores for different companies and I gather prices twice a day at different times.

Comment: So assuming you have a column name store_id.... you should do in your where clasue p_today.store_id=p_yest.store_id

Comment: Hi Nawed - I sent you an email using the contact form on your website.

Comment: Can anyone else help with this problem?